# Create action by a has many through association to assign a favorite_category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### Problem

I'm trying to create a middle table called `category_profiles`, is a intermediate table to assign favorite categories to my profiles, but I can't access to the `category_ids`, that I put in my form, always I got the same validation, Category doesn't exist:

#### Code:

```
class CategoryProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
has_many :category_profiles
has_many :profiles, through: :category_profiles

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
has_many :category_profiles
has_many :categories, through: :category_profiles
```

When I'm doing the create action, my controller can't find my category. How do I fix it?

My create action never find the ids of my categories to assign to the `category_profiles`. It has many through relation:

```
Module Account

  class FavoritesController < Account::ApplicationController

    before_action :set_category_profile

    def index
      @favorites = @profile.categories

    end

    def new
      @categories = Category.all
      @category_profile = CategoryProfile.new
    end

    def create
      @category_profile = @profile.category_profiles.new(category_profile_params)
      if @category_profile.save
        flash[:success] = t('controller.create.success',
                            resource: CategoryProfile.model_name.human)
        redirect_to account_favorites_url
      else
        flash[:warning] = @category_profile.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        redirect_to account_favorites_url
      end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private
    def set_category_profile
      @category_profile = CategoryProfile.find_by(params[:id])
    end

    def category_profile_params
      params.permit(:profile_id,
                      category_ids:[])
    end
end
end
```

#### Form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: @category,method: :post ,  local: true, html: { novalidate: true, class: 'needs-validation' }) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, :id, Category.all.kept.children.order(name: :asc), :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true} ) do |b| %>
      <%= b.label class: 'w-1/6 mr-4' %>
      <%= b.check_box class: 'w-1/7 mr-4' %>
    <%end %>
  </div>
  <div class="md:flex justify-center">
    <%= f.submit 'Guardar categoría favorita', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why have you called your controller "FavoritesController"? Secondly, I think you are trying to create a "CategoryProfiles" controller. This is not necessary. All you need to do is to apply the standard code into the "Categories" controller. Don't forget to add category_profiles to strong params. also post your routes.rb file

Comment: When you call `profile.category_profiles.new`, that's initializing a single CategoryProfile record that requires `category_id` and `profile_id`. You are not passing a value for `category_id`, rather, you get `category_ids`  (plural).

Comment: @maxpleaner thanks, but when I call params.permit(:profile_id,
                      :category_id), occurs the same error, Category its not find, I have the profile because Im doing it with my current user active, but My category never cant find

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, thanks its a good solution, but My CTO gave me this requirement create a new controller to handle the favorites, your idea is the practical solution but now I have to do in a new controller called Favorites

Comment: @JavierAndrésBurgosRoldán you change the `params.permit` call, but did you change the params coming from the front end? You should put a breakpoint in there and see what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want to update intermediate table. So you can do it like this.

```
def create
  begin
    @profile.categories << Category.find(params[:category_ids])

                          Or

    params[:category_ids].each do |category_id|
      @profile.category_profiles.create(category_id: category_id)
    end

    flash[:success] = t('controller.create.success',
                        resource: CategoryProfile.model_name.human)
    redirect_to account_favorites_url
  rescue
    flash[:warning] = @category_profile.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    redirect_to account_favorites_url
  end
end
```

Need to find other better way for error handling using either transaction block or something.

Comment: Thabks Dipak Gutpa

Comment: Is this works for you. Because I have added code with assumption only.